# Java Generics extends

Tags: java, generics, extends

Let's have two classes in Java (7):

```
public class A<T> extends HashMap<T, T>{
...
}
```

and

```
public class B<T> extends TreeMap<T, T>{
...
}
```

Is it possible to have a common base class which these two classes would extend?

Thanks.

Clarification: I want that the classes share the same method

```
public T f(T o){
...
}
```

Comment: They both already extend [`AbstractMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/AbstractMap.html). That's a common base class.

Comment: As khelwood already says, they have a common ancestor. What do you hope to achieve by extending both?

Comment: Also, they implicitly extend `Object`.

Comment: They also both implement `Map<T,T>`.

Comment: Don't know your aim, why a common base class is needed. Maybe a common interface `interface Base<T>` could fulfill your needs, e.g. if its mentioned as something like a MarkupInterface. An implementation of such an interface should be compatible with the extensions of Maps subclasses.

Comment: I want that the classes share the same method which is not in AbstractMap.

Comment: If you want to add a method to both, use an interface.

Comment: Please don't extend `java.util` collection types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that is not possible. Java does not support multiple inheritence, so each class can only extend a single class. Since both of your classes already extends a different class, you cannot create a class that is a superclass of both of your classes.

A possible solution is to use composition:

```
public class MyMap<T> extends AbstractMap<T,T> {
    private Map<T,T> delegate;

    public MyMap(Map<T,T> delegate) {
        this.delegate = Objects.requireNonNull(delegate);
    }

    public Set<Map.Entry<T,T>> entrySet() {
        return delegate.entrySet();
    }

    // Optionally, implement other Map methods by calling the same methods
    // on delegate.

    public T f(T o) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

and then:

```
public class A<T> extends MyMap<T> {
    public A() {
        super(new HashMap<>());
    }
}
public class B<T> extends MyMap<T> {
    public B() {
        super(new TreeMap<>());
    }
}
```

or simply:

```
Map<T,T> aMap = new MyMap<>(new SomeOtherMapImplementation(...));
```

But obviously, now `A` and `B` are not themselves subclasses of `HashMap` and `TreeMap` respectively, so if that's what you need, you're out of luck :-).

Answer (score 1):

As they both implement `Map<T,T>` you can do something like:

```
public class A<T> extends HashMap<T, T> {
}

public class B<T> extends TreeMap<T, T> {
}

List<Map<String,String>> list = Arrays.asList(new A<String>(), new B<String>());
```

Comment: That's an answer to the question: "Is it possible to hold references of `A<T>` and `B<T>` in one data structure." That answer targets in now way to the named problem with a common base. Beside that, it's correct. You can do this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create an Abstract class with the method that you want. And then instead os extends HashMap and TreeMap, use this data structures as fields of your new classes depending on your needs.

For instance:

```
public abstract class MyClass<T> {
   public T f(T o){
       ...
   }
}

public class A<T> extends MyClass<T> {
    private Map<T,T> mapThatINeed;
}
```